# How can I view a website on my server without assigning a domain name to it?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a server with vhosts conf that looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

# My Virtual Hosts:
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@email.com
     ServerName domain

     DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
     DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/public

     # Custom log file locations
     LogLevel warn

     ErrorLog /var/www/domain/log/error_log
     CustomLog /var/www/domain/log/access_log combined

     <Directory "/var/www/dailysongfix/public">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

A typical vhost conf right?  Well I also need to develop a few other sites on the server and these sites don't have domains hooked to them yet.  How can I view them without a domain pointing at them?  I am guessing maybe the IP address and a port, but not sure how to set that up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're going to use named virtual hosts, you need to assign *some* name to the server. In your example, the host will be addressed by the name `domain` (from the `ServerName domain` directive). You can try to contact your server by IP address directly by doing something like `http://123.45.67.89/` but that won't cause Apache to trigger the named virtual host. To do this you will need to add something like this to your `/etc/hosts` file on the client:

```
123.45.67.89    domain
```

Then, you should be able to use `http://domain/` in your browser. This sets up the mapping between name and IP address locally without having to mess with DNS.

The way this works is when the browser sends the HTTP request to the server, it includes whatever text it used after the `//` in the URL in a `Host:` header. Apache takes this text in the `Host:` header and matches it against `ServerName` values in each named virtual host. When it finds a match, it uses that as the server to process the rest of the request. Apache does *not* need to look up the mapping between the host name and IP address, which is why this works if you only change the client machine configuration.

Comment: ...or setup the DNS server inside the LAN to do this. We use both settings in my job.

Comment: I like this solution but I haven't been able to get it to work.  I put my ip address and domain in /etc/hosts like "xx.xx.xx.xx domain.com".  and then i created another vhost entry exactly like the one above in my question but for the new "domain.com".  apache still serves the first vhost listed in my conf file when i go to http://xx.xx.xx.xx  any idea why that would happen?

Comment: can you check your logs in /var/log/httpd/error_log (and perhaps the logs specified by you above)? It sounds like you have a default virtual host (your only current domain) which is being used to handle all requests due to a possible httpd.conf error :)

Comment: the apache log shows no problems and the logs above are empty because they haven't been accessed yet.  i actually have 3 websites running that are all accessed fine.  it seems like apache is never translating the IP to the domain name

Comment: Apache cannot look up the named virtual host if you access your web site by IP address only. You must access it by using its actual name (that matches ServerName), which is why you need to tell your *browser* (through /etc/hosts) how to map that name to the IP address of your server.

Comment: that doesn't really make sense. can you explain how i can tell my browser to map the name to the ip address of my server? also, im not sure that would accomplish what i want to do.  i want to access a website on my server, for example in /var/www/domain/, without having a domain name for it.

Comment: To tell your browser how to map the name (let's say "providercorga.example.com") to an IP address, add a line to your /etc/hosts file as detailed above (for example, "123.45.67.89 providercorga.example.com", substituting your correct IP address of course). Then, when accessing http://providercorga.example.com/ your browser will contact 123.45.67.89 directly without using DNS. On doing so, the browser passes the name "providercorga.example.com" to the HTTP server, and then Apache will look for a matching VirtualHost section with "ServerName providercorga.example.com".

Comment: ah....that is sneaky.  i got confused because i thought you meant put it in /etc/hosts on my server...now it make sense.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use "Alias" instead of VirtualHost, it should work out fine if your PHP applications don't require a fixed URL.

Edit: You can add the aliases to the config you pasted above, just add them before the  container.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the best way to go but you always can do as follows:

1. create dns entry *.example.com that points to ip of your server
2. user ServerAlias in each vhost definition eg: ServerAlias something.example.com

i know i know - it's not exactly what you asked for but i think can solve your problem.

alternativly if your vhosts have exactly the same configuration just put your webpages in /somewhere/{nameOfDomain} and then share /somewhere as another vhost. then you'll be able to access any paged by going to http://myVhost/{nameOfDomain}. this can cause some security risk if in vhosts you have some access rules [ which would be probably not included in 'another vhost' configuration ].

Answer (score 0):

On any standard packaged apache will be setup for use via ip address. which basically doesnt have a virtual host